# How to extend admin users list page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is a image of the WordPress admin user list:

[image]

All I want to do is add an extra column called *add badges*. Column value should be a link to a another page.

I tried editing core files but it ended up realizing it's a bad practice since, because if I make changes I will lose the changes with the next update.

What WordPress does is that it uses `$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Users_List_Table');` to get the table and `$wp_list_table->display();` to display the table.

How to add a field to the table and to extend the admin users list page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the filters `manage_users_columns` and `manage_users_custom_column`.

Code from [Showing user ID on user main page from screen options](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/101322/12615):

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['uid'] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $empty, $column_name, $user_id ) 
{
    if ( 'uid' != $column_name )
        return $empty;

    return "<strong>$user_id</strong>";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the simple answer. BTW I have upvoted on the wp stackexchange too.

Comment: Hi @b__ i am using your code and replacing $columns['uid'] by my meta_key say $columns['company_name'] but it is showing user_ids how i can my company_name values.

Answer (score -4):

i believe if you follow theses instructions you will get what your looking for:

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: please read the question. I know how to add field to the user profile, what I want to do is shown them in the table. BTW thanks for your concern